# What is meant by $d(xy)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$dy/dx$ means derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$
But what is meant by $d(xy)$?
Where is the "with respect to term" here ?

Comment: In a beginning calculus book, d(xy) is nonsense.  Maybe it is a misprint.  In a more advanced book, you may learn about differentials, and then d(xy) may be a differential (or may not, depending on what $x$ and $y$ are).

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828956/please-explain-the-logic-behind-dxy-ydx-xdy) explains the answer, but I'm not positive so I didn't flag as a dupe.

Comment: Is d an operator?

Comment: Yes d is an operator that signifies that we are dealing with Infinitely small changes in a given thing. The given thing in your case is xy.

Comment: @GEdgar : The fact that something is not logically rigorous does not mean that it is just nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

$dx$ can be thought of as an infinitely small change in $x$, just as $\Delta x$ means a change in $x$ that is not infinitely small, and $dy$ would be the resulting infinitely small change in $y$.  Recall that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.
$$

Likewise $d(xy)$ would be an infinitely small change in the product $xy$. If $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t$, then the product rule can be stated as
$$
\frac{d(xy)}{dt} = x\frac{dy}{dt} + y\frac{dx}{dt},
$$
and sometimes it is actually written as
$$
d(xy) = x\,dy + y\,dx.
$$
It can be rearranged into this:
$$
y\,dx = d(xy) - x\,dy
$$
and then both sides can be integrated:
$$
\int y\,dx = xy - \int x\,dy.
$$
In that form, it is called integration by parts.

Comment: Does your answer need mentioning of Product Rule at all? I think you can just explain "Differential" in a deeper sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is the differential of $xy$ which is 
$$
d(xy)=x\,dy+y\,dx
$$
As for a somewhat intuitive interpretation, noticing that
$$
\Delta(xy)=(x+\Delta x)(y+\Delta y)-(xy)=x\Delta y+y\Delta x+\Delta x\Delta y\approx x\ \Delta y+y\ \Delta x.
$$
you can think of it as giving the increment in $xy$ in terms of the increments of $x$ and $y$, when those increments become infinitesimal (so that the second order terms become negligible).

Answer (score 0):

It is called the *differential* of $xy$, and denotes the linear approximation of the increment of $xy$ when $x$ and $y$ have small increments $h$ and $k$:
$$\Delta(xy)=(x+h)(y+k)-xy=\underbrace{xh+yk}_{\text{linear part in $h,k$}}+hk=\mathrm d\mkern1mu(xy)(h,k)+hk.$$

Comment: If I just started Calculus and found that someone told me dxy is just Linear Approximation, I'd honestly get super scared. He's asking what a differential is, Please don't bombard him with Jargon.

Comment: @RishiNandhaVanchi: But that's not jargon: it *is* the definition of a differential, and it's  what physicists use every day.